# Is a passport copy needed while filing the new I-130 for a spouse

Tags: immigration, us-citizens

I have gone through the other questions and the instructions for the new I-130 form.

My concern is that when I filed an I-130 last year (the old version) a copy of the spouse's passport was required, but the new instructions don't mention it. It seems to be ok to not send that copy right now but would that generate an RFE later on? Does anyone have any experience with this scenario?

Comment: "when I filed an I-130 last year (the old version) a copy of the spouse's passport was required" Are you talking about the beneficiary? As far as I know, I-130 has never required the a copy of the beneficiary's passport, in any editions. You can petition beneficiaries who are still in the home country who have never traveled abroad and never had a passport.